# postgresql UPDATE to remove key/value from JSONB data type

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update

Given the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (  
  slots jsonb
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{"0": {"tag": "abc", "info": "xyz"}, "1": {"tag": "def", "info": "uvw"}}');
SELECT slots FROM test;
```

Now I want to delete the `"1"` key/value entirely.  I can set it to `null` as follows:

```
UPDATE test SET slots['1'] = null;
SELECT slots FROM test;
```

But this returns:

```
{"0": {"tag": "abc", "info": "xyz"}, "1": null}
```

Whereas I want it to return:

```
{"0": {"tag": "abc", "info": "xyz"}}
```

What is the command/syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-` operator to remove a key completely

```
update test 
  set slots = slots - '1'
```

Comment: P.S. does this apply to postgresql 14 too?  I know it will work, but postgresql 14 comes with new operators for accessing jsonb data, so just checking there isn't a new version of the `-` operator.

Comment: I don't think the new [subscripting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSONB-SUBSCRIPTING) supports removal of keys